# excel macro to collect data

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm using ms-excel 2016, under windows-7  sp1.

I usually get files workbooks each one has 1 or many sheets

I want to collect data from these files / sheets into master workbook in one sheet

will copy all data mostly but in some columns by different order.

sheets have data like this:

```
id, name, address, telephone,branch,area, ...
```

master sheet will have:

```
id, name,adress,telephone-1, telephone-2,area,branch
```

in most cases if customer has 2 telephones  data entry system enter it in 2 rows,   like this:

```
id, name, address, telephone,branch,area
g13, jake, 7 st., 23456343, ,
k12,johne,ca st., 142635, ,
k12,johne,ca st.,150979, ,
```

in master sheet will be like this:

```
id, name, address, telephone-1,telephone-2,area,branch,verified_id
g13, jake, 7 st.,456343, , ,
k12,johne,ca st.,142635,150979, , ,k12
```

just will add the id at the end to verify that this data copied from the same customer id.

Hope I explained it fine, as a visually impaired unable to show screenshot.

Comment: How comfortable would you be in writing some VBA code? You could start by recording the macro of copying data from one sheet to the master, which would generate VBA code in the background. You would then need to go and edit that code to cycle through all sheets, on all open workbooks - or present a popup form where your can select which sheets to import from where. Lastly a second VBA macro could sort the master sheet by ID and merge the duplicates into a single row. Also have a look here https://professor-excel.com/merge-excel-files-combine-workbooks-one-file/ (also see Office 365 option)

Comment: actually the main problem or challenge for me to merge the duplicates into
a single row, i now do it manually and take more time and efforts,  don't like to use formula like index and match cause it will coppy  data from row to another so if customer has 2 rows will update both, but macro could update one and delete another or leave its cell  blank.

Comment: You can do this easily in Power Query. Merely group by all the columns except `Telephone` (since all the other columns would be identical for a given `ID`), then split out the Telephone numbers as a list which can be expanded over the two columns if necessary.  In VBA, I'd use a dictionary to collect the identical (except for telephone) rows.  Work something out and post back with your efforts if you need help.

Comment: great ron, i was searching for how i do it in power query, but please i didn't understand this (split out the Telephone numbers as a list which can be expanded over the two columns), it's first time for me using power query, many thanks

Comment: @beero since your main problem is deleting duplicates in VBA, have a look here for some example code (https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-remove-duplicates/). This is not particularly difficult code to write, algorithm wise: Loop through every row in range until id cell is blank, if next cell ID = current cell ID, then current row Tel2 = next row Tel1. Delete next row. Next. (This works assuming you manually sort the master list after combining).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using Power Query:

*This assumes that, in the duplicated columns, as you show in your example, all are identical except for telephone. If that is not the case, you may need to do this procedure on multiple columns*

*Annotated* **M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", type text}, {"name", type text}, {"address", type text}, {"telephone", Int64.Type}, {"branch", type any}, {"area", type any}}),
    
    //Group by all the rows EXCEPT "telephone"
    //Do not aggregate (select all rows)
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"id", "name", "address", "branch", "area"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [id=nullable text, name=nullable text, address=nullable text, telephone=nullable number, branch=text, area=text]}}),
   
   //extract the phone numbers as a "List"
   #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Telephone", each Table.Column([Grouped],"telephone")),

   //remove unwanted column and put the phone number column where it belongs
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"id", "name", "address", "Telephone", "branch", "area"}),

    //add the verified_id column
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "verified_id", each if List.Count([Telephone]) = 1 then null else [id]),

    //extract the individual phone numbers from the list, and split the columnt
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Telephone", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Telephone", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Telephone.1", "Telephone.2"}),
    
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Telephone.1", Int64.Type}, {"Telephone.2", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: power query seem more clear in reading, i'll try it practically and back to ask if i need anything. thanks.

Comment: Ron, pls. : could i set telephone as text type, because when i run query as telephone 64 int  it shows errors after loading data, as a data type conversion seem in data source numbers have spaces or dash sign / and ... data need to be clean first,     also in group by step: what do you mean by nullable text or nullable number you mean if cell null or text? ... last point, hope you suggest for me good tutorial for power query ... thanks

Comment: @beero Absolutely. Be sure to change it in all places.  If you run into problems, let me know what the data really looks like.

Comment: @beero `type nullable text` is effectively equivalent to "type text or type null". Otherwise you'd see errors where there are nulls in the column.  It is a bit better, in some regards, than using `type any`.

Comment: @beero In addition to MS documentation, there are many blogs you'll run across with a internet search. Also check out this [Power Query M Primer](https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/11/17/4107/power-query-m-primer-part1-introduction-simple-expressions-let)

Answer (score 1):

A macro (at least for less advanced users/programmers) will only help you if you are performing the exact same action on data AND the data is in the exact same layout.

I suppose it is possible to make a macro for this but it is not necessary.

I would simply go to the last cell in the first row with data (let's say it's B8)

type "B8=B1" and it will show the ID from B1.

Then copy the B8 cell -> select all the remaining cells in the B column with data and paste the formula.

You will now have your matching id at both ends.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: mike: the main task to make one row to each customer, not only to have id in both end, & yes this task usually repeated.

Comment: any solution please??

Answer (score 0):

**A semi-manual solution:**

1. Merge all manually in to master sheets.
2. Sort by ID
3. Put in row E2: =IF(A2=A3, D2, "") *
4. Now copy and paste as values column E (telephone2)
5. Hit "Remove Duplicates" on the Data ribbon, select only ID column and you're done

[image]

- There is unfortunately a small problem with step 3 - if you already have data in column E / telephone 2 from a previous merge. To resolve it, set a filter on the header row and filter for blanks only. Then copy and paste the formula down into the blank cells only. Alternatively create a new telephone 2 column in F and put in F2 =IF(A2=A3, D3, E2)